# In CiviHR, is it possible to display the open vacancies on the frontend?

Tags: civihr

Using CiviHR 1.4, is it possible to create some open vacancies and display them on the frontend, so that people interested in those positions can apply for them?

If it is possible, I couldn't figure out how to do it.

If it is not possible, do you know when this feature is planned for? I looked at this [wiki page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/HR/CiviHR) and I see that self-service is planned for version 1.5. However, from the descriptions there it wasn't really clear to me whether this would allow people to apply for open vacancies from the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in CiviHR.

Publication of jobs on the non-profit's website, and receiving applications from there will be part of CiviHR 1.6. It is scheduled for completion by the end of 2015 : http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/HR/CiviHR+-+Version+1.6+Basic

Hope this helps.

- Ruchi